# Vagrant 'box could not be found' error

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, vagrant

I've installed Vagrant and VirtualBox to simulate Hadoop management (Apache Ambari). According to its installing documentation, i've done everything to create a vm (with 'vagrant up' command). I've installed manually lucid32 box file and placed it to the directory but it still says:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The box 'lucid32' could not be found.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get a box up using the latest install following this process.

```
# From your home directory, install the template box
vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box

# From your project directory
vagrant init lucid32
vagrant up
```

Using Apache Ambari:

```
# clone from GitHub
git clone https://github.com/u39kun/ambari-vagrant.git

# Append these entries to ambari-vagrant/append-to-etc-hosts.txt
# ubuntu 12.4 hosts
192.168.12.101 u1201.ambari.apache.org u1201
192.168.12.102 u1202.ambari.apache.org u1202
192.168.12.103 u1203.ambari.apache.org u1203
192.168.12.104 u1204.ambari.apache.org u1204
192.168.12.105 u1205.ambari.apache.org u1205
192.168.12.106 u1206.ambari.apache.org u1206
192.168.12.107 u1207.ambari.apache.org u1207
192.168.12.108 u1208.ambari.apache.org u1208
192.168.12.109 u1209.ambari.apache.org u1209
192.168.12.110 u1210.ambari.apache.org u1210

# Modify your hosts file
sudo cat ambari-vagrant/append-to-etc-hosts.txt >> /etc/hosts

# Get up and running
cd ambari-vagrant/ubuntu12.4
vagrant up
```

Comment: Ok. It solved but this time, it says "The machine with the name 'c6401' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment." Do i have to create a new machine with VirtualBox? If so, which type of OS do i have to use it with Vagrant?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to open VirtualBox directly when using Vagrant. What commands are you calling with "c6401" to get that error?

Comment: vagrant up and then /sh.

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What is "/sh"? I haven't ever seen/needed/used that command. What are you using for your primary OS? Did you modify the Vagrantfile in any way?

Comment: ./up.sh <# of VMs to launch>

Comment: I am following this guide : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ambari, so I'm not sure how to test whether or not it's running correctly. However, I was able to get a cluster running and see 10 new machines in "running" state in VirtualBox. There was no use of lucid32 anywhere though.

Answer (score 1):

> There was a problem with the configuration of Vagrant. The error message(s)
>   are printed below:
>
> vm:
>   * The box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found.

For me, this was a simple matter of using too old a version of vagrant (version 1.0.1).

Download the latest from: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

And then:

$ sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.8.5_x86_64.deb